# how to read an .atom file from the Data Liberation Front

Tags: xml

I downloaded my Blogger history from [Google Takeout](https://www.google.com/takeout/), and got an '.atom' file.  Are there any utilities in Ubuntu that I can use to easily read the archive?  It's just an XML file and I can see that all the important text is in there, but I was hoping for something that would give me a prettier view of the entries.

Comment: Have you tried LibreOffice Writer?

Comment: If it is an XML I would start by trying to open it in a browser.

Comment: If you want you can ask in Software Recommendation, since that kind of software is quite rare to find.